# How can I hide an Application Bar on certain Pivot Pages in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, nullreferenceexception, application-bar

I think this has a trivial answer but I'm not getting it. Basically I have a Windows Phone 8 app that contains a Pivot, and application bar. I want to hide the application bar when a certain page in the Pivot is navigated to.

What I did was add the following code in the `Pivot_SelectionChanged` event:

```
AppBar.IsVisible = !((((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex) == 2);
```

So when the 3rd page is shown, the Application Bar is hidden, and should be shown when the 3rd page is navigated away from. However, when I run the app, I get a NullReference error for the AppBar.

I tried to put it inside `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {    
      AppBar.IsVisible = !((((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex) == 2);
});
```

It works for the first few swipes, but on causes a NullReference exception on the third page.

Am I totally on the wrong track or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007721/is-it-possible-to-show-application-bar-for-one-pivot-item-only

Comment: @Vovich ah yes I saw that post. however, I didn't realize that the ApplicationBar isn't a user-defined name. And I also thought there is another (and different) way of doing this in WP8. But thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use the name given by you to the `ApplicationBar`, use *ApplicationBar* property of the page instead:

```
ApplicationBar.IsVisible = !((((Pivot)sender).SelectedIndex) == 2);
```

i.e. Replace *AppBar* with *ApplicationBar*

Comment: As simple as that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create application bar for certain pivot items of pivot page like this using id.If id =0,it will take automatically pivot page 0.Dont forgot to use appBarUtils.You can find [here](http://appbarutils.codeplex.com/) .By using this,you can choose which all appbars has to be in whole pivot pages and in selective pivot pages.

```
<phone:Pivot>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
            <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>
                <appBarUtils:SelectionMapping SourceIndex="0" TargetIndex="0"/>
            </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>

            <appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="0"   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.money.png" Text="collection" Command="{Binding CollectionPageCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="3"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton x:Name="ConfirmationAppBarButton" IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.cancel.rest.png" Text="cancel" Command="{Binding OrderCancelButtonCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Model.EnableCheck,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

            </appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
        </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really awesome app bar extension to Caliburn.micro framework. It will let you handle app bar visibility and structure from ViewModel, not Code-behind.

https://github.com/kamranayub/CaliburnBindableAppBar

If you havent tried it, I would strongly recommend taking a look at Caliburn.micro for Windows Phone 8. It really does a great job simplifying WP8 development.